# Extract all variable values in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm debugging an old shell script; I want to check the values of all the variables used, it's a huge ugly script with approx more than 140 variables used. Is there anyway I can extract the variable names from the script and put them in a convenient pattern like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ${BLAH} ....
.....
rm -rf ${JUNK}.....
```

to

```
echo ${BLAH}
echo ${JUNK}
...
```

Comment: If this were a _bash_ script, yes, you could ask the shell to list all variables used. Since it starts with `#!/bin/sh` it's not bash, but a POSIX sh script; that doesn't have the extension.

Comment: ...by the way, `[ ${BLAH} ]` and `rm -rf ${JUNK}` are both very bad practice. `[[ ${BLAH} ]]` or `[ "${BLAH}" ]`, both of which avoid string-splitting and glob-expansion, would be safer. Think about how the code you gave would behave with values such as `JUNK='/tmp/foo.d/ /etc/passwd /junk.txt'`, or `BLAH='-n foobar'`

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script as follows:

```
bash -x ./script.bash
```

Or enable the setting *in the script*:

```
set -x
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the script can take many paths based on different conditions and many statements may not be executed. Also it is.. uhm.. kinda cumbersome to track the values to the variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump all interested variables in one command using:

```
set | grep -w -e BLAH -e JUNK
```

To dump all the variables to stdout use:

```
set
```

or

```
env
```

from inside your script.

Comment: @Rnet: If you're echoing them then obviously you have to know them. Otherwise just run the `set` OR `env` command from your script to dump ALL variables on stdout.

Comment: I thought of 'forming' the echo commands dynamically once I extract the variable names...

Comment: Why make things complicated when simple `env` can do just that.

Comment: The script has a lot of internal variables, and env doesn't show them even if executed within the script

Comment: Are you sure env doesn't show script's own variables. I have used it many many times in my complex scripts to dump these values in log files and have never encountered a case when variables aren't dumped.

Comment: @anubhava `env` definitely doesn't show variables not exported to the environment. It may be that you're using `set -a` to export everything unconditionally.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I invariably use set or env and yes have used `set -a` also.

Comment: @anubhava I'd suggest being cautious about that in the future. If you ever put anything security-sensitive into a variable, `set -a` effectively makes its contents public. (How public depends on your operating system -- some make all environment variables readable to the entire world, others only to processes running under the same user account).

Answer (score 0):

In bash, but not sh, `compgen -v` will list the names of all variables assigned (compare this to `set`, which has a great deal of output other than variable names, and thus needs to be parsed).

Thus, if you change the top of the script to `#!/bin/bash`, you will be able to use `compgen -v`  to generate that list.

That said, the person who advised you use `set -x` did well. Consider this extension on that:

```
PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'; set -x
```

This will print the source file and line number before every command (or variable assignment) which is executed, so you will have a log not only of which variables are set, but just where in the source each one was assigned. This makes tracking down *where* each variable is set far easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a (sub)list of the variables declared in your script using `grep`:

```
grep -Po "([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?==\")" ./script.bash | sort -u
```

### Disclaimer: why "sublist"?

The expression given will match string followed by an egal sign (`=`) and a double quote (`"`). So if you don't use syntax such as `myvar="my-value"` it won't work.
But you got the idea.

### `grep` Options

- `-P  --perl-regexp`: Interpret  PATTERN  as  a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below) (**experimental**) ;
- `-o  --only-matching`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with  each  such part on a separate output line.

### Pattern

I'm using a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?==\")` to require an egal sign followed by a double quote.

Comment: It'd be more accurate to match (1) only things which can be POSIX sh variable names on the left side of the `=`, and (2) no whitespace in the line prior to a quote symbol, escape, or `$(`. Even then... trying to write a parser for shell syntax in regex seems like an exercise in futility.

Comment: That's not a robust idea for sure, but it might fit the need of @Rnet

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?==\")"` require an egal sign directly followed by a double quote.

Comment: ...it's also a risk to assume `grep -P` -- not only is it a non-POSIX option, but even GNU grep has it as a compile-time switch, so it isn't guaranteed to be compiled in at all.

Comment: Your regex won't match varnames beginning with an upper case letter (unless you also use grep's `-i` option). Here's an updated one: `'[[:alpha:]_]\w+(?:\[.*?\])?(?==)'` -- that will also match assignments to array elements, uses Perl character classes for brevity, and does not require a double quote following the equal sign (i.e. `num=0`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I quoted the man page which say it is **experimental**

Comment: Oh~ array syntax like: `myvar[213]`, nice