# All arguments into files with correct quoting using "$@"

Tags: shell, unix

I need my bashscript to cat all of its parameters into a file. I tried to use `cat` for this because I need to add a lot of lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > /tmp/output << EOF
 I was called with the following parameters:
 "$@"
 or 
 $@
EOF

cat /tmp/output
```

Which leads to the following output

```
 $./test.sh "dsggdssgd" "dsggdssgd dgdsdsg"
 I was called with the following parameters:
 "dsggdssgd dsggdssgd dgdsdsg"
 or 
 dsggdssgd dsggdssgd dgdsdsg
```

I want neither of these two things: I need the exact quoting which was used on the command line. How can I achieve this? I always thought `$@` does everything right in regards to quoting.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17238437/802365

Comment: What is your *real* purpose?

Comment: I guess he is using it for logging purpose. e.g. `./configure` logs the command line parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you are right that `"$@"` has the args including the whitespace in each arg. However, since the shell performs *quote removal* before executing a command, you can never know how exactly the args were quoted (e.g. whether with single or double quotes, or backslashes or any combination thereof--but you shouldn't need to know, since all you should care for are the argument **values**).

Placing `"$@"` in a here-document is pointless because you lose the information about where each arg starts and ends (they're joined with a space inbetween). Here's a way to see just this:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

printf 'I was called with the following parameters:\n'
printf '"%s"\n' "$@"
$ ./test.sh "dsggdssgd" "dsggdssgd dgdsdsg"
I was called with the following parameters:
"dsggdssgd"
"dsggdssgd dgdsdsg"
```

Comment: +1. Compared to my answer, no loop is required here. Off course, OP can change `'"%s"\n'` to `'"%s" '` if required.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in "$@"; do echo -ne "\"$x\" "; done; echo
```

Comment: `"${@}"` is just plain unnecessary; `"$@"` would do just fine. Also, you don't need it at all; `for x` is the same as `for x in "$@"`.

Comment: You are right. I had tested the code with `var=(1 2 3)` & had loop with var as variable. Forgot to remove {} during posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To see what's interpreted by Bash, use:

```
bash -x ./script.sh
```

or add this to the beginning of your script:

```
set -x
```

You might want add this on the parent script.